# Html/CSS Display flex and align-items center not working on Galaxy Note 3

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, flexbox

I am building an app using Ionic Framework. While I was working on an app, I faced the problem.

When I tested on browser(using Chrome) and Galaxy Note5, everything was fine. However, when I tested the same app on Galaxy Note3, it gave me undesired result.

`display: flex` with `align-items:center` should align `span` inside `ion-row` vertically middle. But it only works in browser such as Chrome (I only tested on Chrome) and Galaxy Note5, not on Galaxy Note3.

What is the cause of the problem? How could I solve this problem? Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**Html**

```
<ion-row (click)="(!this.driver_docs.Insurance ? takePicture('Insurance') : (!this.driver_docs.Insurance.Examination ? view(this.driver_docs.Insurance.ori_info, 'Insurance', 'False') : view(this.driver_docs.Insurance.ori_info, 'Insurance', 'True')))">
    <img class="management-icon" src="assets/images/mypage/insurance.png" />
    <span class="title">Insurance Managment</span>
</ion-row>
```

**CSS**

```
ion-row {
    position: relative;
    height: 57px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3; 
}
.title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 43px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #545556;
}
```

Comment: 1. It's a little unclear what browser you are using on the Note3.  2. Also compare the browser versions, if it is Chrome on both.  3. That is not valid CSS; are you using a pre-processor?

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you for your comment. How could I find which browser is used on Note3? As I mentioned, I am using Ionic 2 so its using scss.

Comment: Same way you figured out on the Note5, perhaps?  Try the answer from Minal Chauhan.  It could be that the browser on the Note3 is too old.

Comment: If you go surf to this site you get the browser info and can then check if it support Flexbox: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/

Comment: Note3 has Chrome 28 on Android(KitKat)

Answer (score 0):

Used `flexbox` with `prefixes`

```
ion-row {
    position: relative;
    height: 57px;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
    .title {
        position: absolute;
        left: 43px;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #545556;
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not help :(

Answer (score 0):

It may be a mobile responsiveness issue, galaxy note 5 resolution is 1140x2560 , while galaxy note 3 is 1080x1920 ..you can try to add @media styles to these resolutions to solve the issue.